# Can't deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk after timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am newish to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and this is the first time I have encountered this issue. I tried deploying a new version via zip upload of  my app to an instance and the updated completed with errors:

"Completed but with Command Line Timeouts", I increased the timeout in the config file and redeployed, after which I got this message.

> During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new
>   application version. To ensure all instances are running the same
>   version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.

This repeats each time  try to redeploy.

I went into the EC2 instance and noticed the the /var/app/ondeck folder was still there.

I assume this is the issue, but i doubt that simply removing this directory would be the answer - unless it is that simple.

The /var app/current version is still present and the app runs fine using the version that was deployed prior to the initial timeout.

I inherited this app it is Laravel and the composer scripts take a while to run.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The error you showed is a normal message that follows a rollback event. If a deployment fails, beanstalk triggers a rollback. This message always shows up if a rollback happens. I would investigate your logs and try to see why your deploy commands are failing.

Comment: Thanks, I have been investigating in the meantime. It appears that the composer installation is taking a LOONG time. The logs just give me an error saying the deploy failed. I assume because the timeout is firing before composer install is dne. Is there a way to see the actual verbose composer output when deploying? I would like to see what if any package is theissue.

Comment: You could always ssh into the instance and run the commands and see what's happening.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced same problem. When I update back previous platform version, it turns to healthy state, and I can deploy now.

[image: Change]
[image: Platform Versions]

Comment: That's fix the issue!