# Cannot deploy Elastic Beanstalk application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk application that I recently updated with an error in the my (Flask) code (one line of Python with an unrecognized named argument) that resulted in an expected server error. I then tried to redeploy a previously functioning version of my app, but got an error that EB was not in a state that allowed deployment. I then attempted to abort the current operation, but got

> User initiated abort was received, however the current step of the operation in progress is not cancellable. The current operation will be aborted as soon as the non-cancellable step(s) complete.

Eventually the abort succeeded, but now all my attempts to update the EB app fail with

> Environment update is starting.
>   Deploying new version to instance(s).
>   [Instance: i-xxxxxxxx] Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].
>   Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
>   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-xxxxxx'. Aborting the operation.
>   Failed to deploy application.
>   ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.

followed by a warning in the events log

> During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.

I'm now stuck in an infinite loop (regardless of where I try to update from: command line, EB console, EB previous app versions), with all of by EB websites down. It doesn't seem like this should be possible and I must be missing come operation I can perform to restart my application with a previously functioning version.

---

**UPDATE:** Here's what seems to have worked:

1. Delete CloudFormation stack
2. Rebuild Elastic Beanstalk environment
3. Repair A records where necessary to use new EC2 instance IP

Why any of this was necessary — and why nothing less drastic touched the problem — remains a mystery.

Comment: Can you just blow it up and recreate it? Might be the fastest approach...

Comment: @Erebus I guess that's the question (that, and how it's even possible for this to happen): What are the steps to "recreate" without losing anything (and without ending up with all kinds lost connections or orphaned resources)?

Comment: each elasticbeanstalk is a cloudformation stack, you can cancel the cloudformation stack. update.

Comment: @ArunK [Here?](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-west-2#/stacks/stackinfo?filteringText=&filteringStatus=active&viewNested=true&hideStacks=false&stackId=arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-west-2%3A824704040214%3Astack%2Fawseb-e-bbjqdramn3-stack%2F5013b0c0-4a69-11e9-9f1b-0a9edf17d014) Can you describe in more detail to make sure I don't destroy something?

Comment: What if you try rebooting the associated EC2 instance(s) manually? I've had success with this in the past, and at this point it can't hurt if everything is already down!

Comment: @Erebus It won't let me reboot. I can stop and then start again, but then I just get right back were I started. (I tired [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50984674/656912) also, but with the same effect.)

Comment: @Erebus FWIW I can ssh but it's super slow and all commands result in `-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory` (even though the instance appears to have successfully run my prompt customizations as specified in my `.bash_profile`).

Comment: @ArunK In desperation I followed your advice and deleted the cloudformaton stack for my EB app. What now? I can't get anything to work now. What's the next step?